# Spring 4 PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer doesn't resolve ${..} placeholders across modules

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration, placeholder

I have two modules in my applications:

- core
- web

The `core` module contains the following property place-holder configuration in the `spring/applicationContext-core.xml` context:

```
<bean id="coreProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/properties/*.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:/profiles/${build.profile.id}/properties/*.properties</value>
            <value>file:${ui.home}/profiles/${build.profile.id}/properties/*.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>

    <property name="properties" ref="coreProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Considering I have the following property:

```
resource.suffix=.min
```

If I inject this value in a `core` `@Component`:

```
@Value("${resource.suffix}")
private String resourceSuffix;
```

The property is properly resolved .

But, if I add the same configuration in a bean inside the `web` module, which simply loads the core configurations as well:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
        classpath*:/spring/applicationContext-core.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

then the property is not resolved and the `resourceSuffix` value is set to the following String literal value `${resource.suffix`.

What am I missing?

Comment: the @Value("${resource.suffix}") is again on a property and not on a constuctur argument right ? 

also you are sure  that the web module bean is instantiated/scanned by spring?

Comment: It's on a field inside a `@Controller` and the bean is scanned as it also has other `@Autowired` beans being injected as well.

Comment: which of the contexts is instantiating the "web" module ?

can you try moving propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer into that context?

Comment: I'll try to duplicate the `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` since I also need to resolve some properties on the `core` module too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has to do with how spring works with pre/post processors.

Basically you can have duplicated definition or use a different mechanism for loading properties.

As much as I know before spring 3.1 duplication is the only way.

More on http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/#parent-child

Comment: Thanks Mite. Now I have to read all Eugen posts to save spare myself from some Spring configuration-related frustration.

Comment: I think @PropertySource is a better choice unless legacy code then duplication is the way to go